# Linear Algebra Question: Row Reduction and Echelon Form

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I am just starting out in learning Linear Algebra and I have been trying to figure out something that has me confused. Per the rules, as I understand them, when reducing a row to obtain a matrices Row Echelon form you can:

**1. Scale - Multiply all entries in a row by a nonzero number**

**2. Replace - Add a multiple of one row to another, replacing the second row with the result**

**3. Swap - Interchange two rows**

This seems to make sense, however when I go to utilize this to solve for the inverse of a given 3x3 matrix A utilizing the identity matrix, where:

```
A = |40   7  29 | 1 0 0 |
    | 0  11  75 | 0 1 0 |
    | 5  25  27 | 0 0 1 |
```

The way I would *think* to start solving the problem would be is to take Row3 and perform the following to obtain a 0 in row 3, column 1:

```
A = |40   7  29 | 1 0 0 |
    | 0  11  75 | 0 1 0 |
    | 5  25  27 | 0 0 1 | R3: 8(R3) - R1 

A = |40    7   29 |  1 0 0 |
    | 0   11   75 |  0 1 0 |
    | 0  193  187 | -1 0 1 |
```

However, when I have worked this out further, it gets to be very large and unmanageable with the large values in row 3 now... I have seen it solved elsewhere on symbolab and their solution in step 1 was instead to perform:

```
A = |40   7  29 | 1 0 0 |
    | 0  11  75 | 0 1 0 |
    | 5  25  27 | 0 0 1 | R3: R3 - 1/8(R1)

A = |40      7     29 |    1 0 0 |
    | 0     11     75 |    0 1 0 |
    | 0  193/8  187/8 | -1/8 0 1 |
```

I guess my main question is, how do you *know* how to solve these and which ways to go about it? Was my first solution never going to work because of how large things were getting or would it eventually have been correct, just more tedious? It just seems like I am supposed to intuitively *know* the magic number to scale, replace or swap with each time and if I choose incorrect it's a nightmare. Are there other rules that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Your third row in the augmented part should be -1 0 8 after that first operation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.